# How can I play my flash film on my DVD player

Tags: dvd, flash

I need some help with flash.

I have filmed a movie on my camera and I want to make a main menu in flash, which is scripted. The main menu has actions such as; play movie, scene selection and special features. Now the main menu works perfect, it has a stop funtction and listen to my commands. But I want to output this flash file so I can watch it on a DVD player.

I tried this once, using a program called something like; "Amor SWF to VCD SVCD to DVD Burner", but when I played it on my DVD, it skipped over my main menu, went black and played the music I had on the main menu (not the music in the movie). How can I play it on my DVD so I can navigate with my main menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use flash (swf) on your DVD player. You cant convert an arbitrary swf to DVD format. What you can do is convert a `*.flv` movie to play in a DVD

You need a [DVD-authoring program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DVD_authoring_applications) they will allow you to import the movie from your camera and help you create chapters and menus.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, if there is some interaction in the swf, you will need to screen capture. I know youtube will convert some swf files.

I am personally grabbing a tape recorder and using the hdmi out to do a seamless screen capture to tape.